# What does "stuff" mean in expressions like 'incredible stuff'?

Tags: word-meaning

I have trouble in understanding the word "stuff" in this context. Does it mean the same thing as "thing?"

> Helen: I won my tennis match 6-0 6-0 last night.
> Sarah: **Great stuff**!

> Commentator: Seven goals in six minutes. This is **incredible stuff**.

> (Everton 0-0 Chelsea)
> **End to end stuff** as both teams give the ball away and counter on each other. Chelsea looking to find Havertz aerially with several crosses while Everton try and find Gordon down the sides

Comment: Approximately, ***stuff*** meanings "thing[s]" in suvch contexts, but you can't really sematically isolate eavch element in a multi-word idiom. ***Great Stuff!*** means ***That's great!*** (where "that" approximately means "whatever is currently the focus of this conversation" (i.e. - "What you said")

Comment: @FumbleFingers So what exactly does "stuff" mean? I'm still unclear by its meaning. Doesb "Incredible stuff" meansl "something incredible" and "end-to-end stuff" mean "something end-to-end?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is the word "stuff" interchangeable with "thing" here? ***Great thing***, *this is **incredible thing***, ***end-to-end thing***.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers says, you shouldn’t try to understand the expression by breaking it down into its pieces, interpreting each, and then assembling their individual meanings into some whole meaning. That reductionist, analytical approach often simply fails.  As an easy example, the plea *Give me a break!* has nothing to do with gifts or donations, and doesn’t involve any breakage either.  That’s just how language works. English anyway.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stuff) has it: "things that someone says or does, when you are referring to them in a general way without saying exactly what they are: *We did some really interesting stuff today*".

Comment: @WeatherVane, that is indeed a meaning of _stuff_, but I don't think that this use of _great stuff!_ can be analysed as containing that meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine I don't see that, but my point was that there seems to be no indication that OP consulted a dictionary.

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary also has a definition for stuff is *"someone's skill or great abilities*". In this context, does it mean skill?

Comment: Perhaps: 'stuff' is very broad, and is being used in a complimentary way in the first two examples. The third is more general, as in the dictionary example "*I have to go now - I've got stuff to do.*"

Comment: *In this context, does it mean skill?* - ***No**!* Why? Because "you shouldn’t try to understand the expression by breaking it down into its pieces, interpreting each, and then assembling their individual meanings into some whole meaning". Please read the comments. Don't just ignore them.

Comment: "Great stuff" is an idiomatic expression. It's just means: Great. But "end-to-end stuff" must mean great skill or abilities of the players **from one end of the field to the other**. However, *this is incredible stuff* means: The play(s) by the players are incredible. So, there are **three different meanings** here. All related.

Comment: I think this question is very interesting and it took me a few minutes to understand all three uses of stuff.

Comment: Oxford Languages says "matter, material, articles, or **activities of a specified or indeterminate kind that are being referred to, indicated, or implied.**" In these cases the 'activities' are the playing of tennis or football.

Comment: @KateBunting It's more like "action", isn't it? Is "stuff" interchangeable with "thing" here?

Comment: **No!** Activities aren't things. "Great tennis playing!" "Incredible football playing!"

Answer (score 3):

Three different meanings:

1. In general, *mostly* British, it's an expression.

Helen: I won my tennis match 6-0 6-0 last night.
Sarah: Great stuff! = That's great. A great performance.

Anything you admire or like a lot can be "great stuff".

"I saw the *winning movie last night*. It was *great stuff*."

2. Commentator: Seven goals in six minutes. This is *incredible stuff*.

*incredible stuff* or *great stuff* refers to how well the player did in such a short time. Here, it could be said as: What a performance!

3. (Everton 0-0 Chelsea) *End to end stuff* as both teams *give the ball away and counter on each other*. Chelsea looking to find Havertz aerially with several crosses while Everton try and find Gordon down the sides.

OK, so here, it would mean: issues, both teams had issues *throughout the game* or *from one end of the field to the other*. *I was wrong* that it meant great abilities. Here, it seems to mean they did not do great.

Comment: [*Stuff this for a game of soldiers!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stuff+this+for+a+game+of+soldiers%22) [*Any more for any more*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22any+more+for+any+more%22) "meanings" of the word "stuff"? (That one, if you didn't know, is a ***euphemism*** for the "standard" term! :)